# Password mismatch while logging to sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Alright, I have a classic asp application and I have a connection string to try to connect to db.

MY connection string looks as follows:

```
 Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYPC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial
 Catalog=mydb;database=mydb;User Id=me;Password=123
```

Now when I'm accessing db though front-en I get this error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d'
Login failed for user 'me'.
```

I looked in the sql profiler and I got this:

```
 Login failed for user 'me'.  Reason: Password did not match that
 for the login provided. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
 Error: 18456, State:8.
```

What I've tried:

1. checked 100 times that my password is actually correct.
2. Tried this: alter login me with check_policy off (Do not even know why I did this)
3. Enable ALL possible permissions for this account in SSMS.
4. I've tried this connection string: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYPC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydb;database=mydb; Integrated Security = SSPI

And I got this error:

```
  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005' Cannot open database mydb requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to enable Named Pipes in Configuration Manager and restart the services. Also start the SQL Browser service.

Comment: I did this. Still the same error. SQL Browser was on, but I enabled named pipes and restarted PC.

Comment: is this a restored database? sometimes you get user accounts at both a server level and a database level, leading to a password mismatch. Normally you can delete the database-level one and re-map permissions at for the server-level user.

Comment: Hm. But I'm using new account specifically for my local DB.